# Opening source file on click in Xdebug error message with SublimeTex3 xdebug.file_link_format value

Tags: php, macos, sublimetext3, xdebug

I'm configuring Xdebug on Mac with SublimeText 3.
There is an xdebug setting:

```
xdebug.file_link_format
```

to be able to click on file path in error message and open it in editor or IDE.
I can't get the params to work.

This is the inspiration:

```
xdebug.file_link_format = phpstorm://open?%f:%l
```

This is what I'm trying :

```
xdebug.file_link_format = subl://open?%f:%l
xdebug.file_link_format = subl://%f:%l
```

I searched the internet for answers, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

So I moved from Sublime to PhpStorm, and there is a solution for this problem.

You need to ad to the php.ini file in the `[xdebug]` section the following line:

`xdebug.file_link_format = "phpstorm://open?file=%f&line=%l"`